# django: values() dictionnary with many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying (for training purposes) to make an application for a library catalogue. I took the decision to make a Person model for all people involved in creation of the book and join it with Book model through intermediary model (since one book may have several authors, redactors, translators etc), which would describe the role of this person.

The Book model is for an edition of a book. It stores information about book as a piece of literature. For each edition of a book there is a book instance.

The copy model is for a book as an object.

Now I'm trying to make search function. My goal is to display a list of all book which meets search criteria, but have all copies which share the authors and the title (regardless the fact, if it was the same publisher, translator, etc), as one row with the number indicating the number of copies.  So, I understand, I should use `annotate` with `Count` on `values()` dictionnary. But I'm not able to get all information I need while using `values()`.

If I make a query searching by the book title, I have all creators in the `values()` dictionnary. But if the search criteria is author, the values dictionnary keeps only the name which was used to filter, so if the book has two or three authors, I don't get their names.

Here are my models (for Book model only the relevant fields, to make shorter):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    born = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    creators = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Creator')
    
class Copy(models.Model):
    on_shelf = models.BooleanField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    remarques = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    signature_mark = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    approuved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Creator(models.Model):
    AUTHOR = 'A'
    TRANSLATOR = 'T'
    REDACTION = 'R'
    INTRODUCTION = 'I'
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        (AUTHOR, 'Autor'),
        (TRANSLATOR, 'Tłumacz_ka'),
        (REDACTION, 'Opracowanie, redakcja [Nazwisko Imię]'),
        (INTRODUCTION, 'Wstęp, posłowie'),
    ]
    
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

Here are my queries:

By title:

```
book = Copy.objects.filter(book__title='Rozwój cywilizacji amerykańskiej tom 1-2').values('book__creators__name', 'book__creator__role','book__title')
```

The output is:

```
{'book__creators__name': 'Garczyński Stefan', 'book__creator__role': 'T', 'book__title': 'Rozwój cywilizacji amerykańskiej tom 1-2'}
{'book__creators__name': 'Święcka Teresa', 'book__creator__role': 'T', 'book__title': 'Rozwój cywilizacji amerykańskiej tom 1-2'}
{'book__creators__name': 'Beard Charles', 'book__creator__role': 'A', 'book__title': 'Rozwój cywilizacji amerykańskiej tom 1-2'}
{'book__creators__name': 'Beard Mary', 'book__creator__role': 'A', 'book__title': 'Rozwój cywilizacji amerykańskiej tom 1-2'}
```

by author:

```
book = Copy.objects.filter(book__creators__name='Beard Mary', book__creator__role='A').values('book__creators__name', 'book__creator__role', 'book__title')
```

the output:

```
{'book__creators__name': 'Beard Mary', 'book__creator__role': 'A', 'book__title': 'Rozwój cywilizacji amerykańskiej tom 1-2'}
```

The view and template are just a draft, it doesn't work yet. I' trying first to find a solution in the shell.

the view:

```
class Searchg(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SearchForm()
        
        return render(request, 'working/search.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            author = form.cleaned_data['author']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            if author and title:
                books = Book.objects.filter(creators__name__icontains=author, 
                    creator__role='A', title__icontains=title).order_by('title')
                print('a ' , len(books))
            elif author:
                books = Book.objects.filter(creators__name__icontains=author, creator__role='A').order_by('title') 
                print('b ' , len(books))
            elif title:
                books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=title).order_by('creators__name') 
                print('c ' , len(books))
            else:
                print("Please enter search criteria")
            books = books.values('creators__name', 'title').annotate(title_count=Count('title'))
            paginator = Paginator(books, 25)    
            page_number = request.GET.get('page')
            page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
            cache.set('books', books)
        return redirect(reverse('working:book_list'))
```

and template:

```
{% if page_obj %}

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"> Liczba egzemplarzy</th>
      <th scope="col">Tytuł</th>
      <th scope="col">Autor</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        {% for book in page_obj %}
        
      <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter0|add:page_obj.start_index}}</th>
      <td>{{ book.title_count }}</td>
      <td><em> {{ book.title }}</em></td>
      <td> {{ book.creators__name }}</td>   
      
           
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <button class="btn btn-light"><a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a></button>
        <button class="btn btn-light"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a> </button>    
            
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <button class="btn btn-light"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a></button>
        <button class="btn btn-light"><a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a></button>    
            
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: That is expected behavior, since it makes a `JOIN`, and then filters. This is one of the (many) reasons, why using `.values()` is not a good idea. Because you "erase" an extra layer of logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so how should I make a query, to be able to display in the template title, author(s) and number of copies?

Comment: can show the current state ofd the view and the template? Likely rewritingdd it fdrom the existingd one is not that hard.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I'm trying now in the shell, not yet in view and template

Comment: by dropping the `.values()`, you get `Order` objects, and you can iterate over the `Order` objects, and then for example `myorder.book.creators.all()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've posted how the view and template are now.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have no problems to get the authors form the normal queryset. But what I want is to have all books which are the same (same author(s) and title as one row. Let's say, there are 10 books by the same author, each of it in several copies - I want 10 rows with 10 different titles. The details of each book would be other view.

Comment: then you should query on the `Book` model, not on the `Copy` model.

Comment: Book model would have one instance for each edition of the book. But still there might be several copies of it. Copy is a real book, that you can loan, is located somewhere in the library. Book has author, translator, publisher, original language etc. That's why I've chosen to query Copy model. But if I try a query on Book model, the problem presists - if I use normal queryset, each edition is separated record. If I try to group it by author(s) and title, I loose authors which were not in the query. The goal is to be able to search a book with partial information on it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem a book may have let's say 3 edtions. The library may have several copies of each edition. So there would be 3 Book instances (for each edition) and several instances of Copy (for each real book). In this view I need the number of copies.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the (many) reasons why using [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) is often not a good idea. One typically uses this to group on a special field, etc. Not to obtain values.

Furtherdmore you probably want to query on the `Book` model, not on the `Copy` model, since that will make it harder to render each book with one record. You thus can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

books = Book.objects.filter(
    creator__name='Beard Mary',
    creator__role='A'
).annotate(
    ncopies=Count('copy')
).prefetch_related('creator_set')
```

and then in the template, you can render this for example with:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.title }}: {{ book.ncopies }} copies
    {% for creator in book.creator_set.all %}
        {{ creator.person.name }}: {{ creator.role }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here the `.creator_set` will *not* take the filtering of the `QuerySet` into account, since this is handled in a separated query.

You can also query on the `book.copy_set.all` in the template, to retrieve all related `Copy` objects.

Comment: I've tried this solution. It still doesn't group different edition of a book (so different Book instances) in one entry...

Comment: @maria: well when are two different `Book`s the same edition? The `QuerySet` will only return `Book` objects, normally no duplicated books, so that means the same book can not be repeated (for exampe through a different `Copy`, since we do not even consider `Copy`s).

Comment: @maria: you should of course get rid of the `books = books.values('creators__name', 'title').annotate(title_count=Count('title'))` part, since that will "collase" the queryset to records.

Comment: Two different Book instances would be two different editions. But I want in this view to have different edition grouped. As long as it is the same book - title and author(s). There is quite a lot of books which were edited several times. In this view I want to treat it as one entry.